# Django migrations dont work. Have to delete the db and start fresh eveery time

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a django project which works fine.
However, each time there is a change in my models (when I add attributes to my model), the migrations stop working. There is usually some sort of error or the migrations will not execute.
The only way for me to make the migrations to work is to drop the database and start fresh.
This is a very strange behavior and cannot work in a live/production environment.
I recently had to delete the db in the production environment and it was very messy.

Is there a way to fix this ? Isnt this strange that Django makes it harder to work with migrations when it claims that migrations make everything easy.
Am I doing something wrong ? I dont know where to start from.

Comment: Can you give give an example of what "attribute" you're adding? And what specific error you get from adding "X" attribute please?

Comment: Are you running `makemigrations` and `migrate` after each change on the models?

Comment: What is your migration workflow? Can you specify step by step what you are doing (maybe with an example)? You do commit your migrations to source control right? "_usually some sort of error_" **What** error do you get? Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Before you run python manage.py migrate, are you running python manage.py makemigrations?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you don't need to delete your db when there is something wrong with migrations.

When you edit something in models then you need to migrate manually using below command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #This value will come after makemigrations, it can be either 0001 or 0002 or 0003 and so on.

python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have run the following command sequentially.

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`

*If you are getting migrations-related errors then please read the error carefully.*

Mainly this type of migrations-related error occurs for the inconsistency in your migrations file. This is not a proper solution you are just dropping your database every time. Firstly you should be more concerned while writing models. Lastly, you can modify your migrations file to remove inconsistency or cross-check `django_migrations` table with your migrated migrations.
Best of luck :)